# Write checkBoxGroup to file and read from it

Tags: r, shiny

I created a Shiny App which includes a `checkBoxGroup`. When called, this element returns a vector with the selected choices. I can write this to file using `write.table()`and it creates a CSV-file in which a line looks like this:

```
Jota 5 5 nature3 5 5 FALSE c("choice1", "choice2", "choice4") property c("choiceA", "choiceB", "ChoiceD", "choiceE", "choiceK") 5 5
```

But reading this file back using `read.table()` seems to be tricky as it returns in

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>     Line 9 doesn't have 12 arguments

I assume that `read.table()` has difficulties to parse the vectors in the CSV file. Is there any workaround besides flattening the structure and turning every choice into a separate, TRUE/FALSE value with a unique column?

#### EDIT: Example App

As suggested, I put together a dummy app which replicated the problem. It is built on this [article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html#local) by Shiny. Unlike described above it uses `write.csv()` and creates a new file for every form submit but the problem is the same.

```
library(shiny)

fields <- c("name", "groupInput")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("name", "Name", ""),
    checkboxGroupInput("groupInput", "Select from list", choices = c('abc', 'def', 'ghi')),
    actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300)
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    formData <- reactive({
      data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
      data
    })

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
      saveData(formData())
    })

    output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
      input$submit
      loadData()
    })   

    outputDir <- "responses"

    saveData <- function(data) {
      data <- t(data)
      # Create a unique file name
      fileName <- sprintf("%s_%s.csv", as.integer(Sys.time()), digest::digest(data))
      # Write the file to the local system
      write.csv(
        x = data,
        file = file.path(outputDir, fileName),
        row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE
      )
    }

    loadData <- function() {
      # Read all the files into a list
      files <- list.files(outputDir, full.names = TRUE)
      data <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
      # Concatenate all data together into one data.frame
      data <- do.call(rbind, data)
      data
    }
  }
)
```

When you run it and check more than one box in the `checkBoxGroup` the CSV that will be stored looks like this:

```
 "name","groupInput"
 somename,c("abc", "def", "ghi")
```

The existence of the vector in the CSV seems to cause an error in `read.csv`, namely:

```
Warning: Error in read.table: more columns than column names
Stack trace (innermost first):
    87: read.table
    86: FUN
    85: lapply
    84: loadData [/Users/alexanderjulmer/Code/test-storage/app.R#45]
    83: exprFunc [/Users/alexanderjulmer/Code/test-storage/app.R#25]
    82: widgetFunc
    81: func
    80: origRenderFunc
    79: renderFunc
    78: origRenderFunc
    77: output$responses
     1: runApp
```

I think this is because the vector is not properly parsed within the data.frame which I doubt is possible. So I think it would be best to split the data from `checkBoxGroup` into several columns. But then, how to do that?

Comment: Can you provide your `write.table()` call and maybe describe what behaviour you want from reading the files back in (or better yet, create a simple working app to demonstrate the problem)? If you want to write to a CSV, I think the workaround would be to treat your checkBoxGroup inputs as a single character string. But whether that's going to be useful to you at the other end is unclear from the question.

Comment: I added an example which clarifies my question, I hope. I think the problem is, that `checkBoxGroup` returns a vector which requires special treatment before being stored.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to avoid is having a separate column for each possible `checkBoxGroup` input - the alternative to this that I see is to treat any combination of them as an element of length 1 so that it can be read by `read.csv` as such. In your example app, if more than one is checked, the checks are a list with length 3, and read.csv understandably doesn't really know how to handle that.

To address this problem, my approach is to first unlist the elements of `checkBoxGroup` and then collapse the elements into a character vector, and stick that to the "Name" text input. All of this is done in your assignment to `formData`:

```
formData <- reactive({
  data <- sapply(fields, function(x) input[[x]])
  chks <- unlist(data[[2]])
  data <- c(data[[1]], paste0(chks, collapse=", "))
  data
})
```

This gives you a table of two columns, where the second is a comma-separated set of checkbox inputs. (Here, I've broken that process into two steps for clarity, but there's no reason you couldn't put them into one line of code if you want to.)

However, I'm still not clear how you intend to use your data, and therefore whether a character string will be useful to you and solve your ultimate problem...